# Which is the correct way to process an uploaded file in Django and return content from the file?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-middleware

These are the options I know about:

1. To use a custom view based on FormView, which I've done, but I have not yet tried the processing part and don't know how complicated it would be to call the uploaded file.
2. To use a custom view, and after uploads completes, to call a new function to process the file before returning response. I tried it and although it may seem more complicated, at least I understand what is going on behind the scenes.
3. There are many middleware layers I know little about.
4. Maybe there is something that I'm missing or I'm doing wrong.

About me: I've studied Django for about one year.
Many thanks!

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you add the file to your model, you can get it's path later at any time. If the processing you need to do is heavy, you should run it asynchronously.
You can access the file like you would with Python.
If you need to do something with it in the view, django returns the file in request.FILES, and there are methods to work with it (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile)

Comment: the processing is not heavy, I'd like to return the content back to the user, thats why I'd like to know best way to go about. I know I can access the file later from the model, but I want to access the file before returning the result. I know there are many tricks like using a gif spinning animation and some others. The part of async is new to me, thanks for comment

Comment: If you need a file, you can add it to your model. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile